# Listing files in numerical order instead of alphabetical?

Tags: php, linux, unix, ffmpeg

Basically, I have a bunch of files with a common prefix (`logo%d.jpg`) .

When they are viewed using `ls` or even when looping through a directory in PHP, I don't receive them in numerical order, meaning `logo1.jpg, logo2.jpg`.

Instead I get them in alphabetical order, like:

`logo1.jpg, logo10.jpg, logo11.jpg ... logo 19.jpg, logo2.jpg` (Instead of `logo20.jpg`)

Is there a way to ouput them in numerical order? `logo1, logo2, logo3 .. etc.`

Comment: This will only work when you use 01 instead of 1 and 02 instead of 2, and so on. Oterhwise, the above will be the order.

Comment: Oldskool, no, 01 will still make it alphabetical. I tried that. But Hakre got the right idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could put them in an array and sort the array with the [`natsort`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/natsort) function:

```
$array = array('logo1','logo2','logo12');
natsort($array);
```

Which gives ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dYIGVs)):

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "logo1"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "logo2"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "logo12"
}
```

The order you're looking for is often called natural order.

Alternatively, you could prefix the numbers, e.g. if you're already using [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) to name the files, so that the standard sort order would still work:

```
`logo%03d.jpg`
```

Which would generate

```
logo001.jpg
```

for decimal `1`.

Answer (score 2):

Load into an array and use [natsort()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `ls` like you say...

```
ls | sort -n
```

will do the trick.

Comment: yeah, i just figured this out like 3 minutes before you posted it. but now the problem is doing this in PHP. i guess exec?