# Ordering XML foreach results in PHP

Tags: php, xml, foreach, simplexml

here's my code, which displays the results I'm after, but is it possible to list them by order or

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('racing.xml');

    foreach ($xml->sport[0]->event_path->event_path as $gameinfo):

    $description        =   $gameinfo->description;
    $getdate            =   $gameinfo->event['date'];
    $event_id           =   $gameinfo->event['id'];
    $date               =   substr($getdate,0,10);
```

The code

```
    <?=substr($description, -5)?>
```

leaves me with the variable as times, ie: 14:40, 15:50: 14:20: 18:40 etc etc, but they are shown in the order of the XML rather than by time.

Is there a line of code I can include to sort the results by the date variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First some general hint to improve your code:

```
foreach ($xml->sport[0]->event_path->event_path as $gameinfo):
```

Is a bad idea. Instead I make yourself a present and give a new variable (you can thank me later):

```
$gameinfos = $xml->sport[0]->event_path->event_path;
foreach ($gameinfos as $gameinfo):
```

So now you want to sort the `$gameinfos`. Problem here is that those are an iterator and not an array. The `uasort` function (and all the other array sort functions) will not help you any further. Luckily this [has been outlined already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12761317/367456), you can convert the iteration into an array:

```
$gameinfos = iterator_to_array($gameinfos, FALSE);
```

Now `$gameinfos` is an array that can be sorted. To do that obtain the values that define the sort-order (of which `$gameinfos` should be sorted for), I assume it's the time `substr($description, -5)` you've written above:

```
$order = array();
foreach ($gameinfos as $game) 
    $order[] = substr($game->description, -5)
;

array_multisort($order, $gameinfos);

// $gameinfos are sorted now.
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has very useful sort function with ability to define user comparison function. See the link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

Comment: Struggling to get my head around how to apply that to my code though, I'll have a look tomorrow with fresh eyes! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time! I now have my code as:

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('racing.xml');

    $gameinfos = $xml->sport[0]->event_path->event_path;
    foreach ($gameinfos as $gameinfo):

    $gameinfos = iterator_to_array($gameinfos, FALSE);

    $order = array();
    foreach ($gameinfos as $game) 
    $order[] = substr($game->description, -5) ;

    array_multisort($order, $gameinfos);

    // $gameinfos are sorted now.

    $description        =   $gameinfo->description;
    $getdate            =   $gameinfo->event['date'];
    $event_id           =   $gameinfo->event['id'];
    $date               =   substr($getdate,0,10);
```

This is only returning one result though, I'm thinking I've gonewrong some where along the line?